# Why do some mesh vertices not shrinkwrap to the target object?

Tags: mesh, vertices, shrinkwrap, project

My objective is to displace the vertices of one mesh to match the positions of the vertices of another mesh.  Both meshes are composed of the same number of vertices, located at the same XY locations but with different Z locations.  I have been able to use the shrinkwrap modifier (using the project wrap method along the Z axis with the positive and negative directions enabled) to get essentially the result I am aiming for, except that some of the vertices along part of the mesh boundary are not moving to the corresponding vertices of the target object (see highlighted part of the screenshot below).

[image]

Here is a link to download the blender file -
[shrinkwrap_mesh.blend](https://unitedwaterconservation-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/patricko_unitedwater_org/EZtVkZk88w5KoQumnKsgem0BXQS-8hCP_VDuzYxoJRVGVg?e=oHck8Y)

I am hoping someone can explain why these vertices are not projecting to the target object and offer a solution so that all vertices displace to the corresponding vertices located at the same XY locations.

Comment: i think it might be just a rounding issue. Just increase the target size by 1.002 and it works.

Comment: it looks like they are missing the face they should project onto (even though they are at the exact same X and Y location), I don't know why, but you can just move very slightly this edge and it will project correctly

Comment: Thank you Chris and moonboots for your responses! That works for me too.